# Error:InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview, indexing

I have a two **listviews** named **lvsubject** and **lvcurchecklist**.I have also a button. This button will load the selected items in lvsubject to the lvcurchecklist.

```vb
Private Sub btnadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click
    Dim ctr As Integer
    For ctr = 0 To lvsubject.Items.Count - 1
        If lvsubject.Items(ctr).Checked = True Then
            sSql = "Select * from tblsubject where subid ='" & lvsubject.Items(ctr).SubItems(2).Text & "'"
            execSQL(sSql, False)

            If RD.Read Then
                With lvcurchecklist.Items.Add(RD(0), 0)
                    .SubItems.Add(RD(2))
                    .SubItems.Add(RD(3))
                End With
            End If
        Else
            sSql = "Select * from tblsubject where subid ='" & lvsubject.SelectedItems(ctr).SubItems(2).Text & "'"
            execSQL(sSql, False)
            If RD.Read Then
                With lvcurchecklist.Items.Add(RD(0), 0)
                    .SubItems.Add(RD(2))
                    .SubItems.Add(RD(3))
                End With
            End If

        End If
    Next
    ctr += 1
End Sub
```

It throws error

> InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.

In this line:

```vb
sSql = "Select * from tblsubject where subid ='" & lvsubject.SelectedItems(ctr).SubItems(2).Text & "'"
```

tblsubject:

> subid -holds the subject id
>   
> yrlevelid -holds the year level id
>   
> subjectcode -holds the code of the subject
>   
> subjectdesc -holds the description of the subject
>   
> units

Comment: Shall we guess which line has the error?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Note: that has not been the correct, safe way to create SQL for many years. Always use SQL parameters - Alwazs.  A DataGridView would work much better with databased data and require less code and casting to use it.  Also if `ctr` is the loop control variable, you probably do not want to also increment it in the loop.

Comment: already edited it .

Comment: Ok, so `lvsubject.SelectedItems(ctr)` : `ctr = 1` throws the exception. The reason is you are iterating over *all* the items, and using that indexer to index *selected* items. The loop doesn't guarantee that there are 2 items selected. You should validate this situation. Most likely, it's just a typo and it should be `lvsubject.Items(ctr)`

Comment: already changed it to `lvsubject.Items(ctr)` but when I clicked the button , it loaded all the items of the lvsubject to the lvcurchecklist.It is supposed to load the selected items to the lvcurchecklist

Comment: Then iterate over lvsubject.SelectedItems.Count -1 and use SelectedItems everywhere instead of Items